# Solve $y' = \cos^2 (x) * \cos^2 (2y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been studying DE all the day.  I know how to solve questions in form:

$y' - y = h(x)$

I can not figure out how to approach to this question. Can you give me some hint?

$$y' = \cos^2(x) * \cos^2(2y)$$

Comment: Is it $\cos^2(x) \cos^2(2y)$?

Comment: By $\cos(x)^2$ do you mean $\cos (x^2)$ or $\cos ^2 (x)$ ?

Comment: I mean $cos^2(x)$

Comment: I mean $cos^2(x) * cos^2(2y)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Separation of variables. Write:

$$\int \dfrac{1}{\cos^2(2y)}~ dy = \int \cos^2(x) ~ dx$$

Comment: You nailed it! +1